# "_" underscore in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a problem, when I try to run these commands. Problem come from the formula expresion, since `"_"` is a syntax error, but I need exactly that formula in my Excel cells,

How could I solve it out?

```
Sub Prueba_Fernando()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("B:B").Columns.Insert
    Range("B1").FormulaLocal = "=EXTRAE(A1;HALLAR("_";A1;2)+1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR("_";A1;1))"
        Set h1 = Sheets("Hoja1")
        h1.Range("B1").Copy
        For Each h In Sheets
        u = h.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        h1.Range("B2:B" & u).PasteSpecial xlAll
        Next
        MsgBox "Fórmulas aplicadas"

Dim xColIndex As Integer
Dim xRowIndex As Integer
xIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
xRowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, xIndex).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(3, xIndex), Cells(xRowIndex, xIndex)).Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Información copiada a Portapapeles"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the problem lies in the formula.

It is caused by `"`, when you want to have double-quete inside a string, you need to double it, otherwise it will be interpreted as end of the string, thus errors.

Use this line:

```
Range("B1").FormulaLocal = "=EXTRAE(A1;HALLAR(""_"";A1;2)+1;LARGO(A1)-HALLAR(""_"";A1;1))"
```